# No decode delegate error in AHK while using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, autohotkey

In Windows when I run `convert.exe source.tif -compress Group4 output.pdf` there is no error and the output is created successfully. However, when I use AutoHotkey I get an error:

```
Error:  0x80041771 - 
Source:     ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1
Description:    convert: 420: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508: 

convert: 410: no images defined `' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235:
```

My code:

```
IM := ComObjCreate("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1") 
IM.convert(22_2R.tif,-compress Group4,niach.pdf)
```

Comment: Try passing the values as strings `IM.convert("22_2R.tif", "-compress Group4", "niach.pdf")`. When it comes to the COM object's function and syntax: I suspect that most people have never worked with ImageMagick, it may be of help if you provided the parameters the `convert` function expects.

Comment: I provided exacly the parameters that the `convert.exe` expects. If I use qootation marks I get the following error: `onvert: 410: unrecognized option `-compress Group4' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1229:`.

Comment: Are you positive that the `convert` *method* is parameterized exactly the same way you call `convert.exe`? Have you found any documentation on that?

Comment: Unfortunetly, I cannot find any documentation on the method `convert`.

Comment: How about this? `IM.convert("22_2R.tif", "-compress", "Group4", "niach.pdf")`